# JSON read from aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I created an aspx file that act as JSON result.

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

I have another page (another domain) that read that JSON. But I got `syntax error: invalid label` when calling the JSON value.

```
$.getJSON( "http://a.com/json.aspx?format=json&jsoncallback=?" , function(data) {

       alert(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: What did you get? Does you url work correct?

Comment: where did you get the error ? and why you have aspx and not a handler - use a handler to return your results. - Do you have see that you have two `?` on your line.

Comment: @Aristos Do you mean a generic handler? (ashx)

Comment: @Archer Yes a generic handler (ashx) as you say.

Comment: Have you considered using a WebService/WCF Service instead of a generic handler?

Comment: @Aristos I know it's OT, but I wondered if that was a "correct" way of doing it as I adopted that method myself recently with all my ajax calls.  Thanks for validating my choice :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the server to output JSONP, *not* JSON.  JSONP is different.  JSONP is used when the server is on a different domain then the client.

JSONP is actually just a JavaScript file, so it should be served with `Content-type: text/javascript`.  When serving JSONP, you should wrap the JSON in the value of `jsoncallback`.

So, your web server should output something similar to:

```
jQuery12345({"name":"joe","age":22})
```

Where `jQuery12345` is the value of the `jsoncallback` parameter in the query string, which will be automatically set by jQuery.

```
$.getJSON( "http://a.com/json.aspx?format=json&jsoncallback=?" , function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

jQuery will *automatically* replace the `?` with a value.

More info on JSONP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP